# Why a Pattern (design pattern) must describe a relationship?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm learning design patterns and I'm reading the book: JavaScript Design Patterns by Addy Osmani.
Explaining how a pattern must be considered as a real pattern, he writes this as a part of the rules:

> It must describe a relationship: In some cases it may appear that a
> pattern describes a type of module. Although an implementation may
> appear this way, the official description of the pattern must describe
> much deeper system structures and mechanisms that explain its
> relationship to code.

But I don't get it. I don't understand what he means with "type of module" and why a pattern must describe a much deeper system structures.

If anyone could explain me in a better way what he meant I'd appreciate it!

This is the [link of the book](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#introduction).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript there are a bunch of different ways of packaging your code into modules, as opposed to other languages which may have a single standardized way. So, various ways of modularizing your code are recognized as common "patterns" that people use. Some are CommonJS (which I believe Node uses), AMD, and the new browser-native ES Modules.

But those different modularization patterns are about more than just how you package your code. They reflect how modules on a system interact with each other, how they are loaded (asynchronously or synchronously?, etc.), how new the system is, is it a browser or server-side system, etc. So, even though someone might be tempted to say that a pattern like UMD or CommonJS or ES Modules are just module formats, the characteristics of those approaches reflect things about the system, which means the coding patterns you use to use those formats also reflect the system.

So I think he is saying that code patterns, even those related to module formats, are about relationships between different things in the system.

Comment: Thanks so much @xdhmoore. Your answer helped me a lot Now I understand what Addy meant! :D